# Arquivo de queries do Magento

Tags: php, mysqli, magento

Boa tarde,gostaria de saber aonde fica o arquivo que faz as querys no Magento. uso a versão 1.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A classe que executa queries depende do driver que está configurado no Magento. Se estiver usando mysqli seria nessa classe: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Mysqli.php

As queries são geradas em diferentes partes do sistema, mas normalmente são representadas não com SQL diretamente, mas através de collections. A classe Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection por exemplo pode ser usada para buscar produtos, e essa classe herda da collection genérica, que por sua vez usa a Zend_Db_Select para construir a query.